# When instantiating a new class in javascript, what's the harm in not assigning it to a variable?

Tags: javascript, class

So, say I have a class (not a great example but it works for this purpose):

```
function Apple (type) {
    this.getInfo = function() { 
       alert('this apple is green');
    };
    this.getInfo();
}
```

and I want to create an instance of it, so I would typically do:

```
var apple = new Apple();
```

However, in my scenario, because the instance will execute immediately, I don't need the variable, so I just want to do:

```
new Apple();
```

which I know is possible, but what I don't know is what javascript will do behind the scenes. Will it create a memory reference anyway? Will it put some token into global variables? Or does it just run a one time executing class instance?

essentially, I'm asking what the harm in just using "new Apple();" is.

Update

Since this is clearly too ambiguous to get the advice i was looking for let me be more specific.  At my company we use a standard classing structure for javascript files simply for consistency.  This is the structure i'm talking about (mind you uses the class design from http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/):

```
MyClassName = Class.extend({

   init: function (/*param1, param2, etc*/) {
      // this method is called immediately when the class is instantiated.
   },
   destroy: function () {
      // this is your clean up method.
   }
});
```

There are times when MyClassName will not need to be assigned to a variable simply because the intent is for the init method to start the whole thing, so short of lint picking up the usage of "new MyClassName();" to be an error what will core Javascript do is my ultimate question.

Comment: why not make it a function?

Comment: As @DanielA.White that means you should probably just have a function. Furthermore, you could introduce memory leaks, especially if you have any closed over variables inside of the constructor.

Comment: This is a simplistic example, not what i'm actually trying to code.  In practice i'm using Simple Class Inheritance design by John Resig http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/ but in some cases i don't need to ever reference the variable so i didn't want to have some global variable living serving no purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People have already addressed why you *shouldn't* so I'll say what actually happens. Since your object uses `this` a new memory reference will be created. Assuming you don't pass that reference *to* anything (i.e., store a reference to the object in another object or in a closure context) and it doesn't reference any external, persistent values (anything in a closure context that is used elsewhere) then it will be collected during the next garbage collection cycle.

[This article specifically talks about V8's memory model](http://jayconrod.com/posts/55/a-tour-of-v8-garbage-collection) but most Javascript engines follow a similar model.

**TL;DR** It's not considered good practice but assuming you don't store any references to the new object, you won't be any worse for wear.

Answer (score 2):

Most JS linters will flag instantiating a class without assigning it to a variable or property, because it indicates that either:

- You made a mistake, and actually need a reference, or
- You're calling the constructor for its side-effects (as is the case here), in which case you'd be better off calling a function instead.

In the latter case, it is likely (though it depends on the JS environment) that you are allocating memory you won't use by instantiating an object you don't reference. It's also (though this is opinion) usually a Bad Idea to have side effects in your constructor, as they undermine developer expectations about what creating an instance will do, and they can lead to hard-to-find bugs. It's usually simpler to put the side-effect code in a method and call it:

```
function Apple (type) {
   this.getInfo = function() { 
       alert('this apple is green');
   };
}

var a = new Apple();
a.getInfo();
```

Comment: so for a more complicated example is it better to wrap the call in a function so say function() { var a = new Apple(); }(); rather than leaving it in the global scope or just assigning it to a variable?

Comment: That's a lint error too, for the same reasons (unused variable). Better to not have side effects in the constructor at all, or make the constructor into a function.